# Cubic Grassmann term

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, grassmann-numbers

Consider a Grassmannian action with a cubic interaction as follows

$$L_{int} = -i(\theta_1\theta_2\dot{\theta}_3-\dot{\bar{\theta}}_3\bar{\theta}_2\bar{\theta_1})$$

where $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ are Grassmann variables. If we were to compute the canonical momenta with respect to $\theta_3$ we will get something like
$$\pi_3 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}_3} = -i\theta_1\theta_2 + \cdots$$ where $L$ is the full Lagrangian. Obviously, the above is a primary constraint of some sort. Now, because the operator representation of $\pi_3$ is $\partial \over \partial\theta_3$, which is Grassmann odd, how do we reconcile this with the fact that in the constraint  $$\pi_3 +i\theta_1\theta_2+\cdots\approx 0$$ we have Grassmann even term $\theta_1\theta_2$? Isn't this a contradiction or at least a bit problematic?

Edit: Just modified the interaction to make Hermitian.

Comment: Your Lagrangian is of odd grading (which introduces various problems) so your momentum is even.

Comment: Dr. user44690: How does the free Lagrangian look like? Or what is the difference between $L$ and $L_{int}$?

Comment: @Qmechanic Just consider an arbitrary Lagrangian involving three Grassmann variables $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ upto one time derivative. So the free Lagrangian would obviously be quadratic. This is the cubic interaction that can potentially exist in such a general setting, hence, my question.

Comment: So the full Lagrangian does not have definite Grassmann parity?? The free part is Grassmann-even while the interaction part is Grassmann-odd??

Comment: @Qmechanic One can multiply the free part with a 'constant' grassmannian if you like to maintain Grassmann parity.

Comment: To ensure that everybody are on the same page, consider to explicitly write the full Lagrangian in the question.